# Transcluding nested directive gets rendered twice

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

I have created two directives, one for simple text-input box (apt-field), one for bootstrap panel with tabbed-view (apt-panel-with-tab).

Here is the Plunker link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CsxOWGXVzkQugdmpdMyl

In the code, you will see I have used apt-field alone which works just fine, and other within apt-panel-with-tab directive in which apt-field directive gets rendered twice.

I have tried it with both Angular 1.4.8 and 1.5.0-rc.0 and the same result.

Would anyone have any clue what I have been doing wrong? Or could this be a bug in AngularJS?

PS:
SO does not allow me to put plunker link without accompanying code, so here is a portion of the code available on the plunker site:

```
app.directive('aptField', [
  function() {
    var directiveObject = {
      restrict: 'E',
      compile: function(elem, attrs) {
        var tpl = null;
        var bindTo = null;
        if (attrs.field) {
          bindTo = 'formData.' + attrs.field;
          if (angular.isDefined(attrs.modelBase)) {
            bindTo = attrs.modelBase + '.' + attrs.field;
            if (bindTo.indexOf('.') == 0) {
              bindTo = bindTo.substr(1);
            }
          }
        }
        var control = {
          tag: 'input',
          attrs: {
            type: 'text',
            class: 'form-control'
          },
          selfClose: true,
          formify: true
        };
        var tpl = '<' + control.tag;
        for (var attr in control.attrs) {
          tpl += ' ' + attr + '="' + control.attrs[attr] + '"';
        }
        tpl += control.selfClose ? ' />' : '></' + control.tag + '>';
        var $tpl = angular.element(tpl);
        if (bindTo) {
          $tpl.attr('data-ng-model', bindTo);
        }
        elem.append($tpl);
      }
    };
    return directiveObject;
  }
]);
```

Thanks.